# Moving a navigation stack to the more-tab

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` on some tab of a `UITabBar`. When I drill down into the navigation controllers tableViews, move it into the more-tab, and then select the entry in the tableview in the more-list, i get the viewController that was visible at the time i left the tab i moved. Clicking on the back-button gets me back to the more-list, with no possibility to get back to the initial root view controller.

It would be perfectly okay for me to have the root view controller appear when i click on the item in the more-list, but i have no idea how to get notified when my viewcontroller is moved, since i am developing a library, and so have no reference to the TabBarController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways is to implement `tabBarController:willEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:` method in UITabBarViewController delegate. And watch for it. If such thing happend then reset you viewController and navigationViewController. This remove your UINavigationController stack, but application will work correctly.

Comment: Yup, i ended up with making it a requirement for using my library that the app using it sends -viewControllerWasReordered to the libraries singleton in `tabBarController:willEnd...`. in -viewControllerWasReordered i basically did excactly that ^^